# How to count the number of children of a node in an XML document in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I have xml similar to this:

```
<parent>
   <child1>
   <child2>
   <child3>
</parent>
```

Now there are 3 children for parent tag.So i need to get number of childern in parent tag.

I am using the following code but it is not working:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a"); nodeList.getChildnodes();
```

How to do this please?

Answer (score 4):

no matter guys i got it thanks for your comments

```
NodeList image = doc.getElementsByTagName("Point");
Node singleTerminalNode = image.item(i);
Element firstLevel = (Element)singleTerminalNode;
NodeList value1Nodes = (firstLevel).getElementsByTagName("ImageFile");
int lengthofimage = value1Nodes.getLength();
```

Comment: Why do you round `(firstLevel)` by brackets? Is it have sense or it's recommended in standards?

Comment: because you need the child tag of point and it can be acheived only in this way ...

Comment: I mean why do you use `(firstLevel).getElementsByTagName("ImageFile");` instead of `firstLevel.getElementsByTagName("ImageFile");`?

Comment: oh doees it work i havent tried it...because firstLevel is of Element and you are passing it to NodeList ...

Comment: you didn't understand me again ;) sorry for my English. I mean that the brackets is NOT necessary in this part of code `... value1Nodes = (firstLevel).getElementsByTag...`

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File(new File(".").getPath() + "\\src\\yourFile.xml");
doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
int childrenCount = doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().getLength();
```

Comment: At first it will return 1 as result, because the root node always all alone. But if you will use `doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().getLength();` that return 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("YOUR_FILE_PATH");
Node tag1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("YOUR_NODE");
NodeList list1=tag1.getChildNodes();
         System.out.println(list1.getLength());
```

Make sure you import org.w3c.dom.* and javax.xml.*